# strlen not giving correct length after memcpy in C

Tags: c

I'm quite confused in this problem. Here's the code:

```
char str[256];
memcpy(&str[0], "Q", 1);
memcpy(&str[1], "5", 1); // everything fine so far
int16_t lenQ = 22;
memcpy(&str[2], (char*)&lenQ, sizeof(int16_t));
str[2 + sizeof(int16_t)] = (char) NULL;
printf("%i\n", strlen(str)); // prints out 2??
```

Logically the length of `str` should be 4, but it's only two. To make things even more confusing, this works:

```
int16_t raw = 0;
memcpy(&raw, &str[2], 2);
printf("%i\n", raw) // prints out 22 as expected
```

So the size of the `str` is incorrect, but I can still actually access the "out of bounds" value. Have I understood this incorrectly? From what I understand, the `str`-array should look like this internally:

```
'Q', '5', /* 22 in bytes, which is 2 in this case */
```

Should I even get the length of the array like that or am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: Null terminators.  Endianness.

Comment: What did your debugger show when you stepped though the code?

Answer (score 8):

An `int16_t` in memory could be either `\0\x16` or `\x16\0` based on the endianness of your machine. In your case it is `\0\x16` and the memory at `str` will end up containing `"Q5\0\x16"`. Hence `strlen(str)` correctly returns `2`, as the `\0` byte terminates the C-style string.

If you want the result to be `"Q522"`, the `lenQ` variable of type `int16_t` should have a value of `12850` which (for all reasonable CPU architectures) is stored in memory as two bytes with the values 50 (`0x32` in base 16) or the ASCII characters `'2'`.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting. Can I easily switch the endianness? I'm quite new to this.

Comment: No. [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) depends on the architecture of your CPU.

Comment: You can use `htons()` to convert a 16-bit number to a standard endianness (the endianness used for TCP/IP networking).